# What am I doing wrong in this integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$ \int_0^1 \dfrac{\ln^3 \big(\frac{1-x}{1+x} \big)}{x} dx $$

Put $u = \frac{1-x}{1+x}$

Using componendo-dividendo, I get,

$x= \frac{1-u}{1+u} \implies du = -\frac{2}{(1+u)^2} $

$$ \int_0^1 -\dfrac{2 \ln^3(u)}{(1-u)(1+u)}du $$

Write $2$ as $ \big[ (1+u) + (1 - u) \big] $ and seperate the common denominator.

$$ = - \Bigg[ \int_0^1 \dfrac{\ln^3(u)}{1-u} du + \int_0^1 \dfrac{ \ln^3 (u)}{1+u} du \Bigg] $$

Okay I know the values of those 2 integral, so I'll directly use it.

$$= - \Bigg[ - \dfrac{π^4}{15} - \dfrac{7π^4}{120} \Bigg] $$

$$=  - \Bigg( - \dfrac{π^4}{8} \Bigg)$$

$$ = \dfrac{π^4}{8}$$

But when I put it into the calculator, the answer is :

$- \dfrac{π^4}{8} $

Where did I miss the negative sign?

Comment: The limits? $u=1$ if $x=0$ and $u=0$ if $x=1$.

Comment: @mickep Holy crap what the hell!! How could I miss that -_- ..... Thanks a lot :)